# How to debug a Price index that get Stuck

Tags: magento2

Im looking for a way to debug what is happening to our price index. Sometimes when we make changes in categories, or we create new products the price index get stuck. And with this the whole system stop responding, forcing us to restart mysql and reindex price index again.

This issue is happening since m 2.4.2, 2.4.3 and now in 2.4.4-p2

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Debugging the price index issue in Magento can be a complex process. Here are some steps you can take to debug the issue:

1. Check the logs: Check the system and exception logs in the Magento admin panel to see if there are any errors related to the price index. Also, check the MySQL error logs to see if there are any errors related to indexing.
2. Enable developer mode: Enable developer mode in Magento to get more detailed error messages.
3. Check server resources: Make sure that your server has enough resources to handle the indexing process. Check the CPU and memory usage during the indexing process.
4. Use the indexer CLI command: Use the Magento CLI command to run the price indexer manually and see if it throws any errors. You can also use the --debug option to get more detailed information about the indexing process.
5. Check the catalog_product_index_price table: Check the catalog_product_index_price table to see if there are any missing or incorrect values.
6. Clear cache: Clear the Magento cache and try reindexing the price index again.
7. Check indexing mode: Check the indexing mode in Magento to make sure it is set to "Update on Schedule" and not "Update on Save". "Update on Save" mode can cause performance issues if you have a large number of products.
8. Use a profiler: Use a profiler like Blackfire or Xdebug to trace the indexing process and see where the performance issues are occurring.
9. Check for third-party extensions: Check for any third-party extensions that may be interfering with the indexing process. Disable them and see if the issue still occurs.

Debugging the price index issue in Magento can be time-consuming, but following these steps can help you identify the root cause of the problem and find a solution.

Comment: Hello Mayur, I couldnt runnt indexer with --debug option im doing this commant with no luck: bin/magento indexer:reindex --debug catalog_product_price